# Django Settings.py stuck on "SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True"

Tags: python, django

I added the setting

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

to my django settings.py. It works perfectly in production mode so no issues there however, now if I make it the following to test in development mode

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```

I get the following error

```
 You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

What could the issue be? Seems like something is making it not register the new value.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be said about the problem that goes beyond the message you posted. Make sure your URI schema is `http:`!

Answer (score 2):

Clearing browser cache helps.You can do that in the browser settings.